# Estimation of expected mean value E(x)

Tags: probability

I am estimating the probability of the distribution of a discrete random variable $X$ which is defined $P(X=x)=cx(5−x)$ where $X∈{1,2,3,4}$.I already estimated value $c = 1/20 = 0.5$ So next step is estimation of mean expected value $E(x)$.
Can anybody help me to find $E(x)$?

Comment: Double-check your work. I see two errors already. For the expected value, apply the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact $c = \frac{1}{20} =0.05$.

As $P(X = 1) = \frac{4}{20}$, $P(X=2) = \frac{6}{20}$, $P(X=3) = \frac{6}{20}$, $P(X=4) = \frac{4}{20}$ we get that
$$EX = \sum_{k=1}^4 k P(X=k) =\frac{4}{20} + 2 \frac{6}{20} + 3 \frac{6}{20} + 4 \frac{4}{20}=2.5. $$

Answer (score 1):

In general, the way to solve such problems is by considering the follow formulae:

$E(X)=\sum\limits_{x \in \mathcal{X}}x\mathbb{P}(X=x)$, if $X$ is a discrete random variable and $E(X)=\int\limits_{x \in \mathcal{X}} f_X(x) \ \mathrm{d}x$, if $X$ is a continuous random variable. Notice that $f_X(x)$ here is the probability density function (pdf) of $X$. In both formulae, $\mathcal{X}$ is the support of $X$.